# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found error during simple Spring MVC demo application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm new to Spring and trying MVC. I built simple demo app and run it on tomcat 9.0.41
It seems artifact is deploied correctly and problem seems to be in Controller mapping ... it simply can not find my jsp.

here is my project structure

here is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

<!--    <context-param>-->
<!--        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>-->
<!--        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>-->
<!--    </context-param>-->
<!--    <listener>-->
<!--        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>-->
<!--    </listener>-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

<!--    <context-param>-->
<!--        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>-->
<!--        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>-->
<!--    </context-param>-->
<!--    <listener>-->
<!--        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>-->
<!--    </listener>-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

HomeController

```
package com.springmvcdemo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage(){
       return "main-menu";
    }
}
```

and simple main-menu.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>
    Spring Demo MVC - Home page
</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

here is server log

```
"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2021-02-03 07:52:45,945] Artifact SpringMVCdemo:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\tomcat\Tomcat_9_0_41_SpringMVCdemo"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.548 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.41
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.549 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Dec 3 2020 11:43:00 UTC
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.549 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.41.0
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.549 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.549 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Р’РµСЂСЃРёСЏ РћРЎ:             10.0
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.549 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log РђСЂС…РёС‚РµРєС‚СѓСЂР°:           amd64
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.550 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.550 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Р’РµСЂСЃРёСЏ JVM:            15.0.1+9-18
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.550 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.550 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\tomcat\Tomcat_9_0_41_SpringMVCdemo
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.550 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.551 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.551 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.551 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\tomcat\Tomcat_9_0_41_SpringMVCdemo\conf\logging.properties
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\tomcat\Tomcat_9_0_41_SpringMVCdemo\jmxremote.password
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\tomcat\Tomcat_9_0_41_SpringMVCdemo\jmxremote.access
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.552 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.553 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.553 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\tomcat\Tomcat_9_0_41_SpringMVCdemo
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.553 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.553 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.563 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.25] using APR version [1.7.0].
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.563 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.563 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.566 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020]
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.723 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.748 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [347] milliseconds
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.785 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.785 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.791 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
03-Feb-2021 19:52:46.797 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [49] milliseconds
Connected to server
[2021-02-03 07:52:47,043] Artifact SpringMVCdemo:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2021-02-03 07:52:47,364] Artifact SpringMVCdemo:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2021-02-03 07:52:47,364] Artifact SpringMVCdemo:war exploded: Deploy took 321 milliseconds
03-Feb-2021 19:52:56.801 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory РЈСЃС‚Р°РЅРѕРІРєР° РІРµР± РїСЂРёР»РѕР¶РµРЅРёСЏ РІ РїР°РїРєСѓ [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager]
03-Feb-2021 19:52:56.879 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager] has finished in [78] ms
```

i have tried @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET) and ("/main-menu"). Serched stack for similar errors and used sugestions but nothing works. Tried creatign different project from scratch... It's driving me nuts, seems everything is done by the book but still errors

Answer (score 0):

Why is your `spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml` file the exact copy of `web.xml`? Try changing `spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml` to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
 
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvcdemo" />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="main-menu"/>
 
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
 
</beans>
```

**OR...**

In `web.xml` change the mapping as something similar as follows:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/demo/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You will append demo in your url as `http://localhost:8080/demo/`

Comment: Thank you for answer. Tried both ways and same result 404

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete documentation in case you haven't seen it yet:
[Configuring View Controllers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-config-view-controller)

Answer (score 0):

i posted wrong code for spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml

````
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvcdemo" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>```
````

Answer (score 0):

- SOLVED

added extra mapping for method

```
 @Controller
@RequestMapping
public class HomeController {


    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String showPage(){
       return "home-page";
    }
}
```

added to web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

then lowered my language level to 13 since artifact could not deploy because of level 15 was unsupported by Spring (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 59)

then i just call home page from browser

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCdemo_war_exploded/home
```

Maybe this will help someone )